# Is it possible to create a new interface, from an existing interface, with certain top level properties removed based on a condition?

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
interface Example {
  '/api/good/path': {
    get: Record<string, unknown>;
    parameters: Record<string, unknown>;
  };
  '/api/alsogood/path': {
    get: Record<string, unknown>;
  };
  '/api/bad/path': {
    post: Record<string, unknown>;
  };
  '/api/technicallygood/path': {
    get: Record<string, unknown>;
    post: Record<string, unknown>;
  };
}
```

Is it possible to create a new interface from `Example`, but removing all the nested objects that don't contain a `get` property?

My goal is to end up with something like:

```
interface Example {
  '/api/good/path': {
    get: Record<string, unknown>;
    parameters: Record<string, unknown>;
  };
  '/api/alsogood/path': {
    get: Record<string, unknown>;
  };
  '/api/technicallygood/path': {
    get: Record<string, unknown>;
    post: Record<string, unknown>;
  };
}
```

In other words, since `Example['/api/bad/path']` did not contain a `get`, it was removed. All the other keys of `Example` remain, because they contain at least one property called `get`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

```
type RemoveBadEndpoints<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as 'get' extends keyof T[K] ? K : never]: T[K];
};
```

Explanation:

We map through the keys, and if the property has the 'get' property, we use `K` as a key, otherwise, `never` will remove this property since `never` can't be used as a key and is considered as an empty union.

```
// type GoodEndpoints = {
//   '/api/good/path': {
//       get: Record<string, unknown>;
//       parameters: Record<string, unknown>;
//   };
//   '/api/alsogood/path': {
//       get: Record<string, unknown>;
//   };
//   '/api/technicallygood/path': {
//       get: Record<string, unknown>;
//       post: Record<string, unknown>;
//   };
// }
type GoodEndpoints = RemoveBadEndpoints<Example>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChlkByAejh2EoHMB7RgE0pzjAAtyAuZEmTL0IYfgCUICRlBYAeAM5gooegBpkAVxABrEIwDuIAHwBuUkI5Rso6AolSZ8pSpDqtu-UbMWAvubIqGjo4PAVGJlZ2Th5+QSERMWRJaVlFZVUNbT1DEwDkfwsg2koAIzg2Dm4+AQsyHEYlB1TnDLcsz1yfMkLA6hLIBC4QYARQvABPSMqYmvjhUWandNd3bK88uuQGpuTHNJdMjxzvfMLfYmIwCZwUSSxGADcIACEK1BAWBtAwBTkAFWMyAAvLUyABtADSyFAyB0EAmjBgyH+yDgCgoiXIyAg6Egnwx8MRyP+UIAusgAPzIaH8EAQZ5QMn8UmQsnmQrESiUZDXW7IADizBYHy+jB+GNBJG5QmKdGm0WqcS5PKECUWexaKyO6y65hlavqcGsWFsUHsmuWh3axw2PgNBX1qoo-RCYQiwsVsVqDrViSWBzaa06pxVQkKDrllEGw1G4ymnqq3ulzr9GpSVqDHROm19lkaSQzgdW2btTvD5YufJQQtYou+4ElewezzeIs+Dd+cgw2HwEB8QA)

Comment: This works perfectly! For some reason, I never thought use conditionals inside the "key" portion of the type definition. Thank you so much. Marked as answer!